# Flow: Failed to insert record because Contact.Name not assigned

Tags: visual-workflow, compound-fields

I have a Flow that prompts the user for the basic Contact details (First, Last, Title, etc.). I then Assign those values to be `sContact` record variable and of course attempt to INSERT the record. Unfortunately I'm getting the following error

```
The flow failed to access the value for sContact.Name because it hasn't been set or assigned.
```

[image]
I understand that `Name` is a compound field, so my assumption is that if I assign `Contact.FirstName` & `Contact.LastName` that I will have effectively assigned `Contact.Name` but that doesn't appear to be the case. Any insight on this?

Comment: Are you referencing Name anywhere in the flow?

Comment: Nope, this is simply failing on the INSERT component.

Comment: Contact.Name isn't available for use until after the DML (insert) is done; you need to requery the Contact

Comment: So why would this be yelling at me to assign it prior to my insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working... apparently my "Action" component, that you can see clearly is executed AFTER the "Create Records" component, had a `sContact.Name` reference that apparently was causing the fault. What is strange though is that the fault path is triggered not the success component. The error handling subflow is only connected to the Create Records component, so it's not like it took an alternative path to display the issue.

I assume that a "Pause" component could create the space needed for this to not break but seems tacky so for now I'm just going to concatenate First and Last name.